Suppose $ A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ . Prove that $ \mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) $.
Suppose $x \in \mathcal{P}(A)$, given $ A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$,by substituting $A$ as $\mathcal{P}(A)$ ,it follows that $ x \in  \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) $. Hence we can conclude that $ x \in  \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) $ and that $ \mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) $.
Is my proof valid?  Thanks
My edited solution: Suppose $x \in \mathcal{P}(A)$, it follows that $x\subseteq A$. Given $ A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$, it is derived that $x\subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ and hence $x \in  \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) $. Since $x$ is arbitrary, it can be concluded that $ \mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) $.

Why can you "substitute $A$ as $\mathcal{P}(A)$"? I would clean up the language like this: suppose $x\in\mathcal{P}(A).$ Then by definition, $x\subseteq A.$ But since $A\subseteq\mathcal{P}(A),$ it follows that $x\subseteq\mathcal{P}(A),$ and hence by definition, $x\in\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)).$

This might be one of those cases where a more general statement is less confusing to prove: if $A,B$ are sets with $A\subseteq B$, then $\mathcal P(A)\subseteq\mathcal P(B)$. Once this is proven, then simply replace $B$ with $\mathcal P(A)$.

Note there are really two situations where it's acceptable to "substitute $A$ as $B$".  (1) The statement we know is a universally generalization over $A$, so replacing $A$ by anything is actually specialization.  We don't have this in your situation.  (2) $A$ either has the form of "$B$" or it can be reduced to this form.  Usually this is represented by "WLOG" but unless this reduction is a common trick, it requires proof.  In your situation, it seems to be false.

@AdrianKeister Could u clarify on how did you go from x⊆P(A) to x∈P(P(A)) ?

Err, if we have both $ A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ and $A \ne \emptyset $ then $\exists x \in A$. As $ A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$, we can conclude that $\forall x \in A, x \in \mathcal P(A) \implies x \subset A$. Brr, that really sounds weird... Could not that be contradictory with a set being forbidden to contain itself?

@Darren: By definition, the power set of $C,$ denoted $\mathcal{P}(C),$ is the set of all subsets of $C.$ So if a set is a subset of $C,$ it's an element of $\mathcal{P}(C).$

@Daren, your edited solution is correct.

$A\subseteq P(A)\iff A\in P(P(A))$
Hence:
$p(A)\subseteq P(P(A))$.
Due to good comment by Angelo:
Let me clarify:
Let $x\in P(A)$ then $x\subseteq A\subseteq P(A)$ by premise.
Implying:
$x\in P(P(A))$.

Why have you downvoted Ryaron’s answer? It is correct. I am upvoting it.

Ryaron, in order to make your proof more  obvious and evident, perhaps you could write $$B\in\mathcal{P}(A)\implies B\subseteq A\subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)\implies B\in\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$$ Hence: $;\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)),.$
